# How to make the actual references (bibliography) clickable using hyperref?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, hyperref

So I am using `BibTeX` to generate my references and they come out quite nicely. My citations (using `\cite`), my cross-references (using `\ref`) and my contents page entries work perfectly. One problem I am having is that the actual references in the bibliography are not clickable even though they have a `DOI` or a `URL` in the `BibTeX`. How can I hyper reference the actual references themselves?

Additionally, some of my `BibTeX` entries have a `DOI`, some of them have a `URL` and some of them have both. Which one should I keep (should I just merge everything under the URLs since the doi is also a link afterall)?

Comment: there is a package `doi` that activates hyperlinks using doi information in a bibliography.  `texdoc doi` to find out some more details.  the package is included in tex live.

Comment: As @barbarabeeton has suggested use `doi` package (`\usepackage{doi}` is everything you have to do). And use DOI identifier, not URL. DOI has been designed to last longer. If you will use `doi` package include only the DOI identifier itself in the `.bib` file (for example `doi = {10.1234/xxx.222}`). As a result, only the identifier will be displayed in the bibliography, whereas the hyperlink will point to `http://dx.doi.org/10.1234/xxx.222` as it should to.

Comment: not necessarily addressing the question directly, but a nice blog regarding doi and bibtex has been posted recently: https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2016/11/21/new-guidelines-for-doi-linking-and-display/